# Win32API function to join directories?

Tags: c, winapi, path, filesystems

Does the Win32 API have a function for joining two paths?

I can't find it, so I thought I'd ask before rolling my own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you want the functionality of [PathCombine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcombinew) from [Shell Path Handling Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shlwapi-path).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by joining two paths, but you can use [CreateSymbolicLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363878(VS.85).aspx) to link one directory to another.  Another option is [CreateHardLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365006(VS.85).aspx) which is a way to gives files more than one name.  There are also junctions available which are yet another way to link directories.

Note that all of these are yet different from the more user-friendly shortcut (*.lnk) files that get interpreted by the shell.

If you don't have to do this from code, use SysInternals' (now Microsoft's) [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) utility.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a way to combine Paths as strings, not actually combine paths in the file system